# DOS CMD batch: Wrong full pathnames? (parameter extension ~f)

Tags: batch-file, cmd, path, pathname

To list **full pathnames** of files in specified path I may use:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %G IN ('DIR /B "path\*.*"') DO echo %~fG
```

WRONG result: `<current_directory>\*.*`

> ss64.com says: "If a filename with no drive letter/path is expanded to display a drive letter/path the command shell will assume; often incorrectly; that the file resides in the current directory."

This is quite a silly behaviour. However this is probably the problem as DIR here returns a bare filename.

**IS THERE ANY WAY TO AVOID SUCH MISTAKE?**
As it is very easy to make.

I know I can use /S option in DIR command, which makes the result be a full pathname but it also goes through subfolders which is undesired.

Using following syntax everything goes fine but I can't use the advantages of DIR command:

```
FOR %G IN ("path\*.*") DO echo %~fG
```

result: `<path>\*.*`

**Do you have any tips or tricks how to work with DIR and full paths?**

Comment: Another question related: Why doesn't the parameter extension procedure `~f` generate a "file not found" error?

Comment: what if you use `DIR /B /S` ?

Comment: I suppose `DIR /S` also goes thorugh subdirectories recursively which is unwanted.

Answer (score 1):

The environment variable **CD** contains at any time the path of current directory always without backslash at the end.

So you can use for your example:

```
@echo off
set "DirectoryPath=%CD%\path"
for /F "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir /B "path\*.*"') do echo %DirectoryPath%\%%G
```

Therefore whenever using **DIR** with bare output format without using also `/S`, it is necessary to determine first the directory path and reference this path within body of **FOR** loop.

Example on using fixed absolute paths:

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir /B "C:\Temp\My Folder\*.*"') do echo C:\Temp\My Folder\%%G
```

Don't forget the double quotes with path or file name containing a space on other commands than **echo**!

Comment: Thanks, I believe this particular method solves the issue only where _path_ is relative to current directory, however, I understand it is necessary to store the path outside the loop and then combine it with the filename.

Comment: Well, that's right. If on command __DIR__ an absolute path is used, the same path must be also used on file references inside the __FOR__ loop when not using `/S` on command __DIR__ to work with file names with full path.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `FORFILES`? This will give you the full path for any desired folder:

```
forfiles /p C:\Some\Directory\ /c "cmd /c echo @path"
```

`FORFILES` is really mighty as it povides lots of options such as filters, rucursion into subfolders, etc. For more info check [this](http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html) website.

Comment: **ss64.com** is a great site, I mostly look here. However, I run under XP and `FORFILES` is stated here to be available only under XP with **ResourceKit** which I am afraid I don't have. But I may give it a try. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you **really** need to use the `dir` command

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set _subdir=path
set _mask=*.*

call :get_absolute_path _prefix "%CD%\%_subdir%"

rem  Iterate through a list of files, including files in subdirectories
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('dir /b /s /a:-d "%_prefix%\%_mask%"') do (
    rem  The current full file path
    set _f=%%A
    rem  Cut the "%CD%\%_subdir%\" prefix from the current file path
    set _f=!_f:%_prefix%\=!
    rem  Test whether the relative file path has a "subdir\" prefix:
    rem    split the relative file path by "\" delimiter and
    rem    pass %%B and %%C tokens (subdir and the remainder) to the loop
    for /f "delims=\ tokens=1*" %%B in ("!_f!") do (
        rem  If the remainder is empty string then print the full file path
        if "%%C"=="" echo %%A
    )
)

endlocal
exit /b 0

:get_absolute_path
set %1=%~f2
exit /b 0
```

Comment: Thanks. Anyway, is there another option to `DIR`? I want to have a list of files sorted by eg. date, so I thought `DIR` was an easy way.

Comment: No, there is not such option. You can use `dir ... | findstr /r "..."` but the regexp in findstr is lame. And it is not easy to detect subdir in the full file path.

Comment: Sorry, I meant: 'Is there another option **besides** `DIR`?' (option as possibility, not the command option)